# How would the relative rate of reduction of carboxylic acid be if the catalyst used is LiAlH3D?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

How would the relative rate of reduction of carboxylic acid be if the catalyst used is LiAlH3D , LiAlH2D2 , LiAlHD3 , LiAlD4 just thought about it while revising the reaction mechanism of carboxylic acid reduction .